# Play button in custom React AudioPlayer requires two taps for initial play

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have a simple audio player (React/Vite) that automatically or manually moves on to the next track. It works as desired except for the initial press of the play button. The player opens with the pause button displayed. To start the player, the pause button has to be pressed (changes to play), and then the play button is pressed to begin the audio and to use its feature. By all appearances, the code is written to display the play button on the initial load. I can't see where the pause button is coming from on page load. Spent two afternoons on it now...a little help would be greatly appreciated.

The URL to the project: https://github.com/donpayne199/audio.git

Relevant code

```
  const AwesomeDrummers = (props) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <h2 className="section-title">Awesome Drummers</h2>
        <AudioPlayer stories={props} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};


  const AudioPlayer = ({ stories }) => {
  const [textIndex, settextIndex] = useState(0);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  const { text, audioSrc } = stories.stories[textIndex];

  const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(audioSrc));
  const intervalRef = useRef();
  const isReady = useRef(false);

  const startTimer = () => {
    // Clear any running timers
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);

    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (audioRef.current.ended) {
        toNexttext();
      }
    }, [1000]);
  };

  const toPrevtext = () => {
    if (textIndex - 1 < 0) {
      settextIndex(stories.stories.length - 1);
    } else {
      settextIndex(textIndex - 1);
    }
  };

  const toNexttext = () => {
    if (textIndex < stories.stories.length - 1) {
      settextIndex(textIndex + 1);
    } else {
      settextIndex(0);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audioRef.current.play();
      startTimer();
    } else {
      audioRef.current.pause();
    }
  }, [isPlaying]);

  // Cleanup when story changes
  useEffect(() => {
    audioRef.current.pause();

    audioRef.current = new Audio(audioSrc);

    if (isReady.current) {
      audioRef.current.play();
      setIsPlaying(true);
      startTimer();
    } else {
      // true = next pass
      isReady.current = true;
    }
  }, [textIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Pause and clean up on unmount
    return () => {
      audioRef.current.pause();
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="center-container">
        <div className="text-container">
          <p className="text-areas">{text}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <AudioControls isPlaying={isPlaying} onPrevClick={toPrevtext} onNextClick={toNexttext} onPlayPauseClick={setIsPlaying} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};


 const AudioControls = ({ isPlaying, onPlayPauseClick, onPrevClick, onNextClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="audio-controls">
      <button type="button" className="prev" onClick={onPrevClick} aria-label="Previous">
        <BsChevronLeft />
      </button>
      {isPlaying ? (
        <button type="button" className="pause" onClick={() => onPlayPauseClick(false)} aria-label="Pause">
          <FaPause />
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button type="button" className="play" onClick={() => onPlayPauseClick(true)} aria-label="Play">
          <FaPlay />
        </button>
      )}

      <button type="button" className="next" onClick={onNextClick} aria-label="Next">
        <BsChevronRight />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please add relevant pieces of code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio playback is asynchronous `audioRef.current.play()` returns a Promise which will be fulfilled once playback has actually started, so you shouldn't assume playback will start once you call `play()`.

Remove the first `useEffect` and use:

```js
  const AudioPlayer = ({ stories }) => {
  const [trackIndex, setTrackIndex] = useState(0);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  const { text, audioSrc } = stories.stories[trackIndex];
  console.log(stories.stories[trackIndex]);

  let audioRef = useRef(null);

  const toPrevTrack = () => {
    if (trackIndex - 1 < 0) {
      setTrackIndex(stories.stories.length - 1);
    } else {
      setTrackIndex(trackIndex - 1);
    }
  };

  const toNextTrack = () => {
    setTrackIndex(
      prevTrackIndex => (prevTrackIndex + 1) % stories.stories.length
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    audioRef.current = new Audio(audioSrc);
    audioRef.current.addEventListener('ended', () => toNextTrack());

    return () => {
      audioRef.current.removeEventListener('ended', toNextTrack);
      audioRef.current = null;
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audioRef.current
        .play()
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Failed to start playback ", err);
        });
    } else {
      audioRef.current.pause();
    }
  }, [isPlaying]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audioRef.current.src = audioSrc;

    if (isPlaying) {
      audioRef.current.play()
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Failed to start playback', err);
      })
    }
  }, [trackIndex]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="center-container">
        <div className="text-container">
          <p className="text-areas">{text}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="conversation-audio">
        <AudioControls isPlaying={isPlaying} onPrevClick={toPrevTrack} onNextClick={toNextTrack} onPlayPauseClick={setIsPlaying} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default AudioPlayer;
```

PS: auto playback in Chrome will be blocked unless the user interacts with the page.

Edit: I included the whole file this time around, fixed the play/pause behavior, and removed the `startTimer()` function which checks for playback ending, and used an event listener instead, this will schedule playback of the next track once the current one ends.

Comment: Thank you for your response, xanadev, but when I included your code it did not run. Following on your lead I further manipulated the code you had given (which gets me around the double-click issue) however clicking on pause does not pause the audio, but resets it. I am including a link to that project if interested. https://github.com/donpayne199/audio2

Comment: @Don199 I forgot to mention that the project didn't run for me when I first tried it, I had to fix a typo in the `AudioControls.jsx` file to test, the import statements for `react-icons/Bs` should be `react-icons/bs`.

Answer (score 2):

In your original code, when you set isPlaying to true initially, your useEffect for playing audio relies on isPlaying to determine whether to start playing audio. This means that when your component first mounts (i.e., when the page loads), the useEffect runs with isPlaying set to true, which attempts to play the audio immediately.

However, playing audio might require some time to initialize, and if the audio playback hasn't been fully set up yet when useEffect runs, it can lead to unexpected behavior, such as displaying the pause button initially.

By changing the initial state of isPlaying to false, you prevent the audio from playing immediately when the component mounts

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import AudioControls from "./AudioControls";
import "./AudioPlayerCSS.css";

const AudioPlayer = ({ stories }) => {
const [textIndex, settextIndex] = useState(0);
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false); // Change initial state 
to true

const { text, audioSrc } = stories.stories[textIndex];

const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(audioSrc));
const intervalRef = useRef();
const isReady = useRef(false);

const startTimer = () => {
clearInterval(intervalRef.current);

intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
  if (audioRef.current.ended) {
    toNexttext();
  }
  }, 1000);
  };

const toPrevtext = () => {
if (textIndex - 1 < 0) {
  settextIndex(stories.stories.length - 1);
} else {
  settextIndex(textIndex - 1);
}
};

const toNexttext = () => {
if (textIndex < stories.stories.length - 1) {
  settextIndex(textIndex + 1);
} else {
  settextIndex(0);
}
};

useEffect(() => {
audioRef.current.pause();
audioRef.current = new Audio(audioSrc);

if (isReady.current && isPlaying) {
  audioRef.current.play();
  startTimer();
} else {
  isReady.current = true;
}
}, [textIndex, isPlaying]);

useEffect(() => {
return () => {
  audioRef.current.pause();
  clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
};
}, []);

return (
 <>
  <div className="center-container">
    <div className="text-container">
      <p className="text-areas">{text}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="conversation-audio">
    <AudioControls isPlaying={isPlaying} onPrevClick={toPrevtext} 
   onNextClick={toNexttext} onPlayPauseClick={setIsPlaying} />
  </div>
  </>
   );
  };

  export default AudioPlayer;
```

Comment: did it worked? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77039737/play-button-in-custom-react-audioplayer-requires-two-taps-for-initial-play/77091562#77091562) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: No. Sadly the behavior is the same whether initial state is true or false.

Comment: but i tried it in your project and it worked can you provide me with your new updated project? @Don199

Comment: changed isPlaying to true in the project. same result.

Comment: im working on it

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't allow auto play of audios and videos. So you have to have some sort of interaction first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Versions:

1. Maybe the default state of `isPlaying` gets to the `<AudioControls/>`, try to add

   useEffect(()=>{
   },[isPlaying])

   inside  `<AudioControls/>`
2. you have only one place where the play button changes:

   useEffect(() => {
   audioRef.current.pause();

   ```
        audioRef.current = new Audio(audioSrc);

        if (isReady.current) {
          audioRef.current.play();
          setIsPlaying(true);
          startTimer();
        } else {
          // true = next pass
          isReady.current = true;
        }
      }, [textIndex]);
   ```

Try to add `setIsPlaying(true)` to other useEffect